# pyodbc sql results getting cut off

Tags: python-2.7, pyodbc, impala

I have a script as below

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
select_string = "SELECT * from mytable"
cursor.execute(select_string)
data = cursor.fetchall()
print(data)
print len(data)
```

Data is as listed below

```
number      day                 info                       is_true
82          Monday              quick "lazy fox" &amp bear  true
12          Tuesday             why did 'the frog' cross    false
```

when i print the length of the data the is_true column is not being considered because of the quotations/special characters in the info column. Is there a way where i can select * from a table and disregard any quotations that may end the column processing early?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string formatting shouldn't be a problem if you use Pandas for reading the table from the SQL connection. This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect('<SERVER>')
select_string = "SELECT * from mytable"

data = pd.read_sql(select_string , connection)
print(data)
print(data.shape)
```